# Check in gated changes failing every time in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, gated-checkin

I am trying to enable Gated Check-in in Azure pipelines, my every check-in are failing on the final stage **Check in gated changes** with error **[Error]The shelveset _Build_24;Build\BUILD-GUID-NUMBER could not be found for check-in**

[image]

I tried to find the solution for this issue, I found some links to resolve this issue by following steps:
**User setting >> Preview features >> for me >> Disable "Build with multiple queues"**
Unfortunately, I am unable to find this option at the given location.

May be provided solution correct for the older version of Azure, now this option is not available or maybe I am referring wrong place.

Please help me with the solution or provide me some useful links so I can get an idea/understanding from it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to disable the `Limit job authorization scope to current project` option. Project settings:[image]
Organization settings:[image]
Please refer to [this ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/812664/gated-check-in-error-could-not-found-the-shelveset.html).

Comment: I followed your given steps, but still, it's failing